# Finding the lowest price for each category using join sql in Hive

Tags: sql, database, join, hive

I have to write Hive SQL.

I want to find the lowest price for each category. I want to get one row for each category with the category ID, the product ID, the price (lowest price), and the image url columns.
In the example below, we finally need two rows.

Help me. Thank you.

## "category_product_match" table

```
category_id    product_id
1001             500001
1001             500002
1002             500101
1002             500102
1002             500103
```

## "product_info" table

```
prd_id      price      img_url
500001        29000      /app/url/img/500001.jpg
500002        29500      /app/url/img/500002.jpg
500101        8100       /app/url/img/500101.jpg
500102        8100       /app/url/img/500102.jpg
500103        8500       /app/url/img/500103.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select pc.*
from (select pi.*, cpm.category_id,
             row_number() over (partition by cpm.category_id order by pi.price asc) as seqnum
      from product_info pi join
           category_product_match cpm
           on cpm.product_id = pi.prd_id
     ) pc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. Gordon Linoff.

What are the columns of the pc table in your query?

Comment: @minsu . . . All columns from `pi`, the `category_id` and `seqnum`.  To be honest, though, I just used `select *` as a short-hand because the specific columns don't seem to be an important part of the question.

Comment: Hi. Gordon Linoff!
The query you created earlier is well used.
But I want to join a new table.
There are three more "big category id" and "small category id" in the existing table "product_info". This category is different from the previous catalog. I wrote a detailed specification on the new link. Help me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159689/join-with-three-tables-in-hive

Answer (score 0):

use Min aggregate function with inner join and group by with category id

```
 Select category_id ,product_id, Min(price) as lowest_Price,img_url
 from  category_product_match
 inner join product_info on product_id=prd_id
 group by category_id;
```

Demo here [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb8747/3)

Comment: MySQL lets you select columns that aren't in the GROUP BY.  But Hive won't (and most other RDBMS), so this will generate an error (can't select product_id because you didn't group by it...)

Comment: I know that you need to put all the columns in the "select" clause in the "group by" clause.