# Join with three tables in Hive

Tags: sql, database, join, hive

I have to write Hive SQL.

I want to find the lowest price for each catalog. I want to get one row for each catalog with the catalog ID, the product ID, the price (lowest price), the image url, the large_ctgr_id, the small_ctgr_id, the large_ctgr_name, and the small_ctgr_name columns.
In the example below, we finally need two rows.

In addition, there are multiple products in a catalog, and each product is classified into a large category and a small category.

Eventually we have to join the three tables.

There is a similar issue with the link I asked.
([Finding the lowest price for each category using join sql in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112782/finding-the-lowest-price-for-each-category-using-join-sql-in-hive)) In this case, we joined only two tables, and the names of the columns changed slightly.

Help me. Thank you.

## "catalog_product_match" table

```
catalog_id      product_id
1001             500001
1001             500002
1002             500101
1002             500102
1002             500103
```

## "product_info" table

```
prd_id        price      img_url                  large_ctgr_id  small_ctgr_id
500001        29000      /app/url/img/500001.jpg  200            34543
500002        29500      /app/url/img/500002.jpg  201            2345234
500101        8100       /app/url/img/500101.jpg  1020           23252
500102        8100       /app/url/img/500102.jpg  42133          2349823
500103        8500       /app/url/img/500103.jpg  3435           342514
```

## "category_info" table

```
l_ctgr_id     s_ctgr_id    l_ctgr_name  s_ctgr_name
200           34543        computer     notebook
200           3423984      computer     tablet
201           2345234      phone        smartphone
1020          23252        clothes      top
42133         2349823      cup          cup
3435          342514       pen          ink
```